# ASP.NET MVC Pagination Not Working on ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I am using pagination in my project. I have search box and sending searching text to Action Result.

I hitted break point to Search ActionResult. My news and announcements are filling after select queries.

**Search ActionResult**

```
 public ActionResult Search(string searchText,int? page)
    {
     int pageIndex=page??1;
     int dataCount=20;

     dbContext=new dbContext();
     SearchViewModel searchViewModel=new SearchViewModel();

     var news=(from news in dbContext.News
               where news.Title.Contains(searchText)
               select news).ToList();


     var announcement=(from announcement in dbContext.Announcement
               where announcement.Title.Contains(searchText)
               select announcement).ToList();


     searchViewModel.News=news;
     searchViewModel.Announcement=announcement;

     List<SearchViewModel> searchViewModelList=new List<SearchViewModel> {searchViewModel};

     return View(searchViewModelList.ToPagedList(pageIndex,dataCount));

    }
```

**SearchViewModel**

```
public class SearchViewModel
{

   public IEnumerable<News> News {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Announcement> Annocument{get;set;}    
}
```

My models aren't null in view. I am displaying my all data titles after searching. PagedList has showed on view but has only 1 page.

**Search.cshtml**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.ViewModels.SearchViewModel>
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

<div class=container>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
  foreach (var news in item.News)
 {
  @news.Title
 }

 foreach(var announcement in item.Announcement)
 {
  @announcement.Title
 }

}

@Html.PagedListPager(Model,page=>Url.Action("Search",new {page=page}));
</div>
```

I used PagedList in my project before. But I want to use in ViewModel. Where is my wrong ?

Comment: You only create one instance of` `searchViewModel` - using paging on one record makes no sense. And your code is getting all records from the database, not just the 20 you want. And `ToPagedList()` is designed to work with data models (you use an `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`), not view models (for that you could use `StaticPagedList`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for answer. I already getting all data from database. 20 is for trying. How my codes should be ? Will I change List to IQueyable ?

Comment: The whole point of server side paging is to only get the records you want from the database (i.e. just 20, not all of them). And you cannot use `PagedList` for 2 models (and it makes no sense anyway since you will have different numbers of items of each)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understood. But I need to data from 2 tables. I only change List to IQueryable in my code ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I already saw it. You wrote you use and IQueryable<T> in first post. I am asking how can I solve my problem without ViewModels ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176779/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-developer007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToPagedList()` is designed to work with data models, not view models. What you are currently doing is returns all `News` and `Accouncement` records from the database by calling `.ToList()` (which defeats the whole purpose of using server side paging), and the assigning all those records to the property of one instance of your view model, and then applying `ToPagedList()` to that single instance.

You need to change your view model properties to `IPagedList<T>` and then apply paging to each property, not the view model itself. Your view model should be

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<News> News { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Announcement> Annoucements { get; set; }
}
```

and then the controller method will be (note that your linq queries need to include an orderby clause, but I do not know which property you want to order by)

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText, int? page)
{
    int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
    int dataCount = 20;

    dbContext=new dbContext();
    IQueryable<News> news = (from news in dbContext.News 
        where news.Title.Contains(searchText) orderby ?? select news);
    IQueryable<News> announcements = (from announcement in dbContext.Announcement 
        where announcement.Title.Contains(searchText) orderby ?? select announcement);

    SearchViewModel model = new SearchViewModel
    {
        SearchText = searchText,
        News = news.ToPagedList(pageIndex, dataCount)
        Annoucements = announcements.ToPagedList(pageIndex, dataCount)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Then modify the view to

```
@model SearchViewModel
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

... // your form with the input for SearchText

<div class=container>
    @foreach (var news in Model.News)
    {
        @news.Title
    }
    @foreach(var announcement in Model.Announcements)
    {
        @announcement.Title
    }
    @if (Model.News.Count() > Model.Announcements.Count())
    {
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.News, page=>Url.Action("Search",new { page = page, searchText = Model.SearchText }));
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Announcements, page=>Url.Action("Search",new { page = page, searchText = Model.SearchText }));
    }
</div>
```

Note that the `if` block ensures that the page numbers are shown in the case where you navigate to subsequent pages where you might have some `News` items but no `Announcement` items or vice versa. However this does not guarantee that the total number of pages will be correct (there might be say 45 matching `News` records, and 65 matching `Announcement` records)

Comment: Thank you so much again :) It is very clear solution.